# Nagios - How to use check_icmp instead of check_ping?

Tags: centos, nagios

I am newer to Nagios. I am not able to use check_ping because of "problems parsing the output" according to the check_ping command. I have tried setting to SUID as recommended in some threads, but the problem persists. check_icmp works fine. How do I swap the check_icmp command into the service definition? Everything basic I tried failed.

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       my_host
        service_description             PING
        check_command                   check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.geekmungus.co.uk/?p=295

This did it for me.